# Adding Swagger for javax.ws.rs.*

Tags: java, swagger

I have an application using Java 1.7. We are using Maven and use `javax.ws.rs.*` for RESTful api's.

I am looking to add Swagger for the REST endpoints.

I have found the following [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5), but I am not sure if it is the right fit for `javax.ws.rs.*`.

**Question**

Please can someone advise what Swagger documentation to follow for `javax.ws.rs.*`?

Comment: yes you can add

Comment: are you using web application. if you are, then you need to configure in web.xml file